# Array becomes uninitialised after setting it from inner class

Tags: java, android, logging, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

In the code sample I have commented two Log statements, both of which make the same call to the one and only array in the code, yet the second call returns java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 . Help is appreciated.

```
public class DataBaseHandler {
    List<User> downloadedTransporters = new ArrayList<User>();
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    public static void setDownloadedTransporters(User user){
        downloadedTransporters.add(user);
    }

    public List<User> getTransporters(){
        final String TAG = "DatabaseActionTAG";
        Log.d(TAG, "DataBaseHandler.getTransporters() confirmed");

        db.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("registeredTransporter", true).get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){                              
                            Log.d(TAG, "Got Documents Successfuly");
                            int i = 0;
                            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                DataBaseHandler.setDownloadedTransporters(document.toObject(User.class));
                                Log.d(TAG,downloadedTransporters.get(i).getFirstName());//WORKS
                                i++;
                            }
                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents:", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });

        Log.d(TAG,downloadedTransporters.get(0).getFirstName());//DOESN'T WORK
        return downloadedTransporters;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder how the static method ```setDownloadedTransporters``` is being able to access the non-static field: ```downloadedTransporters```. Are you missing the static modifier in front of downloadedTransporter? Do you have a compilation error?

Comment: Maybe you should consider returning a future.

Comment: By the looks of the code, the 'onComplete listener' executes later, after the 'documents' have been got.  So your last couple of lines execute before downloadedTransporters have been filled in.

Comment: @alainlompo, the array was static at one point, I changed it during my debugging process, part of the debugging process was creating the `setDownloadedTransporters` method instead of setting the variable from the inner class but to no avail. It is a runtime error.

Comment: @another-dave that sounds right, how could I make `getTransporters()` wait till onComplete() has run, before returning the array. I think I should call a method from a loop within `getTransporters()` that checks if onComplete() is done, and if not continues to loop the check.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn what is a future?

Comment: Probably some class aptly named Task. May have some value in the future, but not for now.

Comment: @Dylan - use wait/notify on some object you allocate for synchronization.   Caveat: I can't say whether it's a good idea for this method to wait for an asynch operation to complete (I don't do Android programming). The alternative is for this method itself to present an asynch interface, e.g., by returning a Future.

Comment: @another-dave Instead of learning how to handle async threads, I decided to call the method that `getTransporters()` returns the array to, from the inner class. This of course makes the method not reusable however.